# How to sum up column with ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have this DataFrame which contains the following columns :

```
print(df)
               Date     Agent   PDF  Pages    Service  Box
        0   2019-11-07  Mery     1    520        A      2
        1   2019-11-07  Edward   1    569        A      3
        2   2019-11-07  Mery     2    718        A      3
        3   2019-11-08  Edward   2    980        A      2
        4   2019-11-09  Mery     2    717        B      2
        5   2019-11-09  Edward   3    118        B      1
        6   2019-12-10  Mery     1    356        B      2
        7   2019-11-10  Edward   5    248        C      3
        8   2019-11-11  Mery     3    828        C      1
        9   2019-11-11  Edward   4    497        C      2
```

I applied groupby method to get the result below :

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Service','Agent']).agg({'PDF':sum,'Pages':sum,'Agent':len,'Box':sum})

print(df1)
                        PDF  Pages Agent   Box
     Service Agent            
        A    Mery        3   1238    2    23221
             Edward      3   1549    2      .
        B    Mery        3   1073    2      .
             Edward      3   118     1      .
        C    Mery        3   828     1      .
             Edward      9   745     2      .
```

For the Box which is the problem, The number I indicated is not necessary correct. But I must say that the column type is :Object.

My question is how to get the sum of the box column based on the groupby method?

For the type, I tried to convert it to int(), but It gave me the following error:

```
df['Box'] = df['Box'].astype(int)
```

**This error is from the real data :**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-c66ef0a69928> in <module>
----> 1 df['Box'] = df['Box'].astype(int)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)
   5689             # else, only a single dtype is given
   5690             new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,
-> 5691                                          **kwargs)
   5692             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
   5693 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in astype(self, dtype, **kwargs)
    529 
    530     def astype(self, dtype, **kwargs):
--> 531         return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
    532 
    533     def convert(self, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, **kwargs)
    393                                             copy=align_copy)
    394 
--> 395             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    396             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    397 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    532     def astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None, **kwargs):
    533         return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, values=values,
--> 534                             **kwargs)
    535 
    536     def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in _astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    631 
    632                     # _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
--> 633                     values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
    634 
    635                 # TODO(extension)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    681         # work around NumPy brokenness, #1987
    682         if np.issubdtype(dtype.type, np.integer):
--> 683             return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
    684 
    685         # if we have a datetime/timedelta array of objects

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe()

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '111221212--11121111223122333222131'
```

Comment: `df['Box'] = df['Box'].astype('int')` Then try using `df.groupby`.

Comment: this is what I've done and it gave me this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. Do you have any idea what would be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that *Box* column is of *object* type and individual values as **strings**. Check it running e.g. `df.info()`.

In such case *sum* function **concatenates** individual values into a single string.

To have the actual sum (as mathematics defines it), convert *Box* column e.g. to *int* type.

## Edit following a question in the comment

The answer to your question is in the last row of the stacktrace:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '111221212--11121111223122333222131'
```

Although it does not contain any source line number, it does contain the
exact content of the "offending" cell (*111221212--11121111223122333222131*).

It seems that this column has been generated as a result of *groupby* and
then *sum*, for some column containing **strings** not numbers.

So actually you should check the part of code generating the **source** file
which you then read into this *df*.

Probably this fragment of code operates on a DataFrame with the summed
column of *string* type, so just the above content is generated.

Then you read it (into *df*) and attempt to convert it to *int*, which
in this situation is impossible.

Comment: Trying to convert the box column with : df['Box'] = df['Box'].astype('int'). It give me that error : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: The stacktrace should indicate the number of source row in which this exception has been thrown. Check the indicated row, maybe you have some non-integer content there. Correct it and run the code again.

Comment: I edited my question with the error from my real data. Could you pls see if you can find the problem